# How to copy multiple selected rows of listview into clipboard in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have put together this code Selected rows into clipboard from a lisview.

```
procedure TFmainViewTCP.Copy1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
  Str:String;
  k  :Integer;
  lItem:TListItem;
 begin
   repeat
     lItem:=lvConnection.Selected;
     Str:=lItem.Caption;
     for k:=0 to lvConnection.Columns.Count-2 do
      begin
       Str:=Str+'  '+lItem.SubItems[k];
      end;
     Clipboard.AsText:=Clipboard.AsText+ sLineBreak +Str; {copy into clipboard}
   until lItem.Selected=True;
 end;
```

I am not sure if this is working correctly, it does not copy out all the rows for me. Can somebody help me out in this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code does not iterate over all of the selected rows. It just works on the first selected. You need to loop on all the items and process the selected ones...

```
procedure TFmainViewTCP.Copy1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
  s, t: String;
  i: Integer;
  lItem: TListItem;
 begin
  t := '';
  lItem := lvConnection.GetNextItem(nil, sdBelow, [isSelected]);
  while lItem <> nil do
  begin
    s := lItem.Caption;
    for i := 0 to lItem.SubItems.Count-1 do
      s := s + '  ' + lItem.SubItems[i];
    t := t + s + sLineBreak;
    lItem := lvConnection.GetNextItem(lItem, sdBelow, [isSelected]);
  end;
  if t <> '' then Clipboard.AsText := t;
 end;
```

Comment: Nitpicking: I suggest using `sLineBreak` instead of the literal `#13#10`. (And a run through the formatter, obviously. :-P)

Comment: @PA: you should also use the ListView's `GetNextItem()` method instead of looping through all of the items one at a time.  I edited the example accordingly.

Comment: When I used the above code, I received a nil back from the lvConnection.GetNextItem(nil,sdBelow, [isSelected]). If I seed the lItem with lvConnection.Selected, the rest of the code worked as expected.