# Copy Sub Item Of List View Delphi Into Clipboard

Tags: listview, delphi, copy, clipboard, subitem

I have a List View with eight columns and a popup menu. 
[ScreenShot][image]

I have this code which is work great to copy into clipboard all items and sub items when a row or all rows selected.

```
procedure TForm1.CopyURL1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  lv : TbsSkinListView;
  s : string;
  c,f,k : integer;

begin
  lv := bsSkinListView1;
  Clipboard.Clear;
  s := '';

  for f := 0 to lv.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin     
     k := 0;
     if lv.Items[f].Selected then
     begin
       s := s + Format('%s : %s, ',[lv.Columns[k].Caption, lv.Items[f].Caption]);
       for c := 0 to lv.Items[f].SubItems.Count - 1 do
       begin
         Inc(k);
         s := s + Format('%s : %s, ',[lv.Columns[k].Caption, lv.Items[f].SubItems[c]]);
       end;
      SetLength(s, Length(s) - 2);
      s := s + #$D#$A;
    end;      
  end;
  clipboard.AsText := s;
end;
```

What i need is I'd like to copy only the caption of column one (column "Title") with it's sub items [0], and copy the column 8 caption (column "URL") with it's sub items [7] into clipboard, when a row or all rows selected.

Also sometime sub items[7] is empty, and it shouldn't get index out of bounds (7) error message.

From my screenshot above, when i copy the 1st row, the result should return like this

```
Title : 10 Things You Didn't Know...  URL :   <=== this is an empty sub items [7]
```

when 2nd row copied:

```
Title : 10 Things You Didn't Know...  URL : http://www.example.com
```

All rows selected :

```
Title : 10 Things You Didn't Know...  URL : 
Title : 10 Things You Didn't Know...  URL : http://www.example.com
```

i have try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786625/how-to-copy-multiple-selected-rows-of-listview-into-clipboard-in-delphi) but it doesn't meet or not work as i need. I'm using Delphi XE 4. How do i achieve this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What prevents you from copying what you want?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz using the code above, i get all sub items copied, like this: `No : 2, Title : 10 Things You Didn't Know..., Quality : webm 256x144, Size : 3.09 MB, % :  100.0%, Speed : 568.05 KB/s, ETA :  00:00
, status : Done...!, URL : https://www.example.com` while i need only `Title : 10 Things You Didn't Know...  URL : https://www.example.com`

Comment: You have to write code that does what you want. You might want to start reading about the [if statement](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#If_Statements).

Comment: I have learn about if statement. But as a beginner, i can't figure out it properly. i have tried write like this `for f := 0 to lv.Items.Count - 1 do begin`
    `if lv.Items[f].Selected then`
        `s := 'Title :' + lv.Items[f].SubItems[0] + 'URL : ' +` `lv.Items[f].SubItems[7]; ` . Seems does work but i get index out of bonds when subitems[7] is empty

Comment: That is where you would use an 'if'. Test if there is a subitems[7], if there is proceed with the line you pasted, if not, use `s := 'Title :' + lv.Items[f].SubItems[0] + 'URL :`

Comment: i tried your suggestion with this simple code like this: `if lv.items[f].Selected then begin`
      `if lv.items[f].SubItems[7] <> '' then`
        `s := 'Title : ' + lv.Items[f].SubItems[0] + ' URL : ' +` `lv.Items[f].SubItems[7]`
      `else`
        `s := 'Title : ' + lv.Items[f].SubItems[0] + ' URL : ';`
    `end;`
   `Clipboard.AsText := s;`.  Stil i get index out of bonds sub items 7 when its' empty. Can you help me, please? I'm really stuck with that

Comment: subitems[7] is not empty, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I didn't know before if it doesn't exist. Now i can figure out it to works. Many thanks.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your clipboard text contains all of the column values because you are looping through all of the `TListItem.SubItems` values.  If you don't want all of the values, simply don't loop anymore.  Just access the specific items you want.

Try something more like this:

```
procedure TForm1.CopyURL1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  s : string;
  item: TListItem;
begin
  s := '';
  item := bsSkinListView1.GetNextItem(nil, sdAll, [isSelected]);
  while item <> nil do
  begin     
    s := s + Format('Title : %s, ', [item.Caption]);
    if item.SubItems.Count > 7 then
      s := s + Format('URL : %s, ', [item.SubItems[7]]);
    s[Length(s)-1] := #$D;
    s[Length(s)]   := #$A;
    item := bsSkinListView1.GetNextItem(item, sdAll, [isSelected]);
  end;
  Clipboard.Open;
  try
    Clipboard.Clear;
    Clipboard.AsText := s;
  finally
    Clipboard.Close;
  end;
end;
```

With that said, an alternative option would be to use the `TListView` in virtual mode instead (`OwnerData=True`), where you store all of your data in a separate list.  Then you can access your data list directly without having to touch the `TListView` at all.  For example:

```
type
  PMyData = ^TMyData;
  TMyData = record
    Selected: Boolean;
    Title: String;
    ...
    URL: string;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  private
    MyData: TList;
    ...
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyData := TList.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to MyData.Count-1 do
    Dispose(PMyData(MyData[I]));
  MyData.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.bsSkinListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
var
  Data: PMyData;
begin
  Data := PMyData(MyData[Item.Index]);
  Item.Caption := Data.Title;
  Item.SubItems.Add(...);
  ...
  Item.SubItems.Add(Data.URL);
  Item.Data := Data;
end;

procedure TForm1.TForm1.bsSkinListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem; Selected: Boolean);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Item <> nil then
    Item.Selected := Selected
  else
  begin
    for I := 0 to MyData.Count-1 do
      PMyData(MyData[I]).Selected := Selected;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.TForm1.bsSkinListView1DataStateChange(Sender: TObject; StartIndex, EndIndex: Integer; OldState, NewState: TItemStates);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if (OldState * [isSelected]) <> (NewState * [isSelected]) then
  begin
    for I := StartIndex to EndIndex do
      PMyData(MyData[I]).Selected := (isSelected in NewState);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.AddItem1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Data: PMyData;
begin
  New(Data);
  try
    Data.Selected := False;
    Data.Title := ...;
    ...
    Data.URL := ...;
    MyData.Add(Data);
  except
    Dispose(Data);
    raise;
  end;
  bsSkinListView1.Items.Count := MyData.Count;
end;

procedure TForm1.CopyURL1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  s : string;
  Data: PMyData;
  I: Integer;
begin
  s := '';
  for I := 0 to MyData.Count-1 do
  begin
    Data := PMyData(MyData[I]);
    if Data.Selected then
    begin     
      s := s + Format('Title : %s, ', [Data.Title]);
      if item.URL <> '' then
        s := s + Format('URL : %s, ', [Data.URL]);
      s[Length(s)-1] := #$D;
      s[Length(s)]   := #$A;
    end;
  end;
  Clipboard.Open;
  try
    Clipboard.Clear;
    Clipboard.AsText := s;
  finally
    Clipboard.Close;
  end;
end;
```